# Get data from the row of a Dropdown in a Gridview

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a Gridview with a column that has a DropDownList.
I've binded this Dropdownlist with an event on the "SelectedIndexChanged".
The problem is i can't get the value of a label of another column in the same row.

The code is the next:

```
protected void grid_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grdCredenciales.DataBind();

        var dropdown = (DropDownList)sender;
        var row = (GridViewRow)dropdown.NamingContainer;
        var label = (Label)row.FindControl("lblMatricula");

        var value = label.Text; // I get "" in this line.
    }
```

And in the grid i have:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="CredencialesDS" runat="server" />
<asp:GridView ID="grdCredenciales" runat="server" BackColor="White" DataSourceID="CredencialesDS"
    CssClass="DDGridView" RowStyle-CssClass="td" HeaderStyle-CssClass="th" CellPadding="6" AllowSorting="True"
    AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="10" OnRowDataBound="grdCredenciales_OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label7" ToolTip="Matrícula" runat="server" Text="Matrícula"/>
           </HeaderTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="15%"/>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMatricula" runat="server"><%# Eval("Matricula") %></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Label19" ToolTip="Estado" runat="server" Text="Estado" />
           </HeaderTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="15%"/>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dpEstadoCredencial" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grid_OnSelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="comboEstado"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I don't know why, but label.text returns an empty string. As you can see, i am calling the DataBind before, so the label should have a value at this point.

Do you know how can i get the value i need from the label in another column?

Thanks for everyone.

Comment: Can you show your grid definition? Also, try label.Name , it will contain the value if label is displayed and not defined, let me know if it works for you and I'll compose a complete answer.

Comment: I've added the code of the aspx. Check it out!

Comment: Oh, and thanks for your helping.

PD: The Label doesn't have the "Name" property.

Comment: Didn't know we were talking aspx :)

Comment: Yes, is this a problem?

Comment: Not a problem I just can't assist

Answer (score 2):

Check the GridView's `DataSource` before you do the `DataBind()`.  Since you're missing the full ASPX markup, I'm not sure if you're setting the data source programmatically or with a SqlDataSource.

In any case, what will happen often with programmatically-set Data Sources is that they disappear on a `PostBack`, and when you call that `DataBind`, you're really DataBinding it to null, which would explain why you're getting `string.Empty` ("") for the `Label`'s `Text` property.

Comment: Thanks Garrison, it is very helpful. But do you know how can i get the data i need then?

Comment: Your code looks like it will work to give you the data in `value` that you expect, but it won't work if you're DataBinding to `null` as I suspect.  Let's test it.  Put a breakpoint on `grdCredenciales.DataBind();`, then run the code and check the value of grdCredenciales.DataSource or DataSourceID.  If both are empty or null, your `DataBind()` call is breaking your logic.  You can try not doing the `DataBind()` at the beginning, but that's not guaranteed to fix it.

Comment: I've checked it.
The DataSource is null, but the DataSourceID has a value! (the name of the datasource).

If i don't do the databind before, it doesn't work neither.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with DataSourceID, so I don't know if it needs to be set prior to a DataBind like the plain DataSource does.    It seems like it's already set, so I don't know if the DataBind is necessary or not.  Could you update your post with the full GridView markup?

Answer (score 2):

Just verified the code provided by you. It's working completely.
Please make sure in the RowDataBound event of Grid View, you reattach the dropdownlist's SelectedIndexChanged event as below:

```
protected void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("dropdown1") as DropDownList;
                if (ddl != null)
                {
                    ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I used the same code as yours in SelectedIndexChanged event. I'm putting here my aspx Markup:

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
        datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
        autogeneratecolumns="false"

        runat="server"  
        OnRowDataBound="CustomersGridView_RowDataBound">
          <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>' />
                  </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:TemplateField>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                          <asp:ListItem Text="Cat"></asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem Text="dog"></asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem Text="Mouse"></asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem Text="pig"></asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem Text="snake"></asp:ListItem>
                      </asp:DropDownList>
                  </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>

      </asp:gridview>
```

Please provide your GridView markup too for checking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The event is binded correctly, my problem is that when the method on "SelectedIndexChanged" is called, i can't get the value of the other label on the same row.

I've edited the post and i've added the GridView markup. Check it out!
I hope you can help!

Thanks a lot

Comment: ok. So you are using ObjectDataSource. From the Latest update made by you in the Markup, I see there are some attributes Missing for ObjectDataSource. 1.) TypeName , 2.) SelectMethod. To work with ObjectDataSource, Create a class that contains the DataAccess Methods & 0ne more class that provides all the FIELDS of your Table as Public properties. Please make sure the connection string is fine. Let me know if you need the Class files code in case it may help you.